# Lookup column from upper web site in sharepoint

Tags: list, sharepoint, lookup

I have a web site in sharepoint lets call it as 'Master Web Site'

and i have a subsite of 'Master Web Site' and lets call it as 'Slave Web Site'

in 'Slave Web Site' i have a list

```
 -- SlaveList
     --ID
     --Title
     --Address
     --Country (i want this column comes from the upper site list (MasterList))
     ...
```

in 'Master Web Site' i have a list

```
-- MasterList (For all the countries in the world)
```

now i want to add a lookup column to 'SlaveList' from 'MasterList'.

when i try to add a lookup column i only select the lists in the 'Slave Web Site'

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Site Column in your "Master" site.
This should by type of Lookup to the Country column in your MasterList.

After that you can choose this Site Column in your "SlaveList" by Add Existing Site Columns  in your List settings.

Comment: i exactly did this thing. now i have country column in my subsite. However when i create an edit form from this web site, what i see is there is dropdown for countr column, but it does not have any content.

Comment: I think it is a bug of sharepoint designer since when i do same things from browser it works like a charm